# Assign / Set CSS ID to objects in threejs scene

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

I have 3d objects inside a threejs scene. I'd like to assign these 3D objects CSS IDs so I can target them in my document.
Is there any advice on how to achieve this, if possible?